# How do I autofill a spreadsheet with information from another WORKBOOK?

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I have two workbooks.

One is a form that has questions with free form text as an answer box.  These forms are submitted by a various number of people.

The second form is a spreadsheet in list format where I want to have the information from form 1 autocopied/filled onto form 2.

I thought there was an easy way to do this in the previous versions of Excel but I can't seem to do this in the 2010 version.

Answer (score 1):

You should have/create a button on your form that will do the exporting for you.

There will be some VBA code behind the button to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to cells in another workbook by using this formula syntax:

```
=[Source.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2
```

Where "Source" is the name of the workbook and "Sheet1" is the name of the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't that hard. What you need to do is create an object for the workbook you want to copy to. Once you have the object, you can reference it as much as you like.

Example:

```
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("form2.xls")
```

Then you can access it to write data like so ("25" to be replaced by a value in your form):

```
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = 25
```

Just create a button on your form that opens form2 and have it copy the relevent information over to it. You can close form2 afterwards if you like:

```
Wb.Close savechanges:=True
```

I noticed you are new here, so Welcome!, and please remember to accept the answer that helps you most and upvote any other helpful answers.